# Quadcopter navigation with obstacle avoidance?

Tags: uav, moveit, 3d-navigation, pixhawk, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to implement autonomous navigation with obstacle avoidance for quadcopter (which has Pixhawk). All I want to implement is quadcopter being able to move from point A to point B while avoiding obstacles. I am fine with the navigation being in 2D.

I am using Odroid  connected to Pixhawk as the main controller.
I am using Hokuyo URG-04LX-UG01 Scanning Laser Rangefinder for detecting obstacles.

What I figured out till now is there are two options to achieve navigation with obstacle avoidance. Use MAVROS somehow along with Navigation Stack / MoveIt.  I guess as I am fine with navigation in 2D Navigation Stack should be what I should use. Is that correct?

Navigation stack requires 3 sort of data to function: Sensor Data, TF & Odometry data.  I have LIDAR publishing sensor data, so thats fine.

My questions are:

1. How do I get TF and Odometry data (used by navigation stack) using MAVROS? What sort of data should I use? How do I do that?
2. Can I use MoveIt if I dont have map or anything and only 2D LIDAR data?
3. In future I want UAV to navigate in 3D. If answer to 2nd question is yes then should I switch to MoveIt instead?  And any links for resources to read specifically about moveit and pixhawk will be very helpful.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224235/quadcopter-navigation-with-obstacle-avoidance?/) by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2016-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-09-21**:
Have you gotten any further in this? I am doing something similar

**Comment by [Nikka](https://answers.ros.org/users/28163/nikka/) on 2017-07-11**:
Hi, did you complete your project, I want to do similar kind of project, any suggestion for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. You have to generate that. You can make a URDF model of the quadcopter or build a transform publisher to get the TF data. For the odometry you can get the imu data from /mavros/imu/data and if you have a px4flow (or knockoff) from /px4flow/raw/optical_flow_rad. I also use laser scan matching to simulate odom data using the lidar. Pass the data through an EKF or UKF (I use robot_localization) to get a combined odometry estimate.

I am planning to use moveit for 3D navigation but have only just started looking into it. If you have gotten any further in this I would like to hear about it.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0